# Webview/Webkit not working as expected

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, youtube, webkit

This is my first time posting here. So please bear with me. I am using Webkit to display some content from YouTube in a webview.

### Background

- OS: OS X 10.10.2
- SDK: OS X 10.10

### Problem

As I stated before I am using a WebView to display content from YouTube. But, I ran into some problems which I have outlined below

When attempting to use the YouTube's fullscreen action this is what happens:

#### Test One (Using Flash):

**Observations**:

- What wrong I did: When using the Flash player on YouTube’s website when I attempt to play a video everything worked fine.
  Additionally, when I clicked the YouTube video’s full screen button the window did appear in full screen. However, it is not completely fullscreen (the menu bar is still visible)
- What I expected: I expected that the video would have entered fullscreen entirely. In Safari everything works fine.

#### Test Two (Using HTML5):

**Observations**:

- What I did: When using the HTML5 player on YouTube’s website when I attempted to play a video everything worked fine. However, when I clicked the YouTube video’s full screen button nothing happened.
- What I expected: I expected that the video would have entered full screen. I did noticed when doing this ins Safari everything worked as expected.

Can someone please help me with this matter? I have searched everywhere and found nothing.

Here is a sample of the test app I did to illustrate this problem:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[[self webView] mainFrame] loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [self.window setContentView:self.webView];

    //When YES WebView will use Flash if available, else will use HTML5
    BOOL shouldUsePlugin = YES;

    if (shouldUsePlugin == YES) {

        [[[self webView] preferences] setPlugInsEnabled:YES];

        //Test 1: Using Flash

    } else {

        [[[self webView]preferences]setPlugInsEnabled:NO];

        //Test 2: Using HTML5

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution to this specific problem but I know from experience that the "old" WebView class has major issues with web plugins (including Flash). Here are two of my repro cases for Apple that show that plugins don't work correctly using WebView: https://github.com/lemonmojo/WebViewPluginTest https://github.com/lemonmojo/WebViewJavaTest   Now my suggestion to you is to migrate to the new WKWebView (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) which handles plugins way better and generally is more future proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those using the newer WebKit API (`WKWebView`) see my answer here: [WKWebView Mac Browser Enable fullscreen html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988219/wkwebview-mac-browser-enable-fullscreen-html5/56998745#56998745) for enabling fullscreen on HTML5 content

Answer (score 0):

just use their youtube player framework. they have pods for that.

> pod 'YouTubePlayer'

you only need to load, play, stop, clear. and your work is done